# Bot editing with the mediaWiki API

Tags: mediawiki, mediawiki-api

I'm trying to write a little bot to edit mw pages for hours now and can't seem to get it right. At this point I'm not even sure whether the problem is in my code or whether I've misunderstood the process. I won't post my code - only the process. Please tell me, if I got at least that right! (This is mediaWiki 1.19 btw)

1. Login with password and username:

   POST: action=login, lgname=XXX, lgpassword=XXX
2. First login fails with:

   result=NeedToken, token=XXX
3. Extract cookie header from first reply and be sure to send it with all subsequent requests:

   /^Set-(Cookie: \w+_session=[^;]+);/
4. Login again but this time with the token and the cookie header:

   POST: action=login, lgname=XXX, lgpassword=XXX, lgtoken=XXX
5. Request an edit token with:

   POST: action=query, prop=info, intoken=edit, titles=XXX
6. Extract the editToken and edit with:

   POST: action=edit, bot=1, title=XXX, md5=md5(content), text=content,
   token=editToken

The edit succeeds but for some reason it's an anonymous edit o_O

Answer (score 0):

Seems my cookie handling was insufficient. I didn't realize that I had to capture ALL cookies - not just the session cookie. All is well now.

Comment: You should probably use a proper HTTP request library that can handle cookies for you. Newer versions of MediaWiki will require bots to understand Set-Cookie headers that delete cookies.

Comment: I couldn't find a PHP library I liked so I decided to write my own - project-specific - library from scratch. It might be a good idea to turn the library into a universal one. If I do so, I'll definitely follow your advice!   
I might switch to JavaScript and [nodemw](https://github.com/macbre/nodemw) though...

Comment: If you use curl (which you probably should if you use PHP), just set both `CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR` and `CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE` and that will take care of everything for you.